# Align a horizontal form at the center of the webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a form whose input fields are all aligned horizontally end to end. I want it to be aligned at the center of the webpage.I have tried using `margin: 0 auto`. That didnt help. I have also tried `position: absolute` and `left top` but that didn't give me desire results. [image]

also submit button aligned at the center.

here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>APT - Aviation | Travel | Hospitality</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">

        <div class="background-wrap">
            <video id="video-bg-elem" poster="images/clouds-from-an-airplane-window-picjumbo-com.gif" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop muted>
                <source src="video/clouds.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/APT-LOGO-PNG.png" ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Enter contact">
    </div>
    <button style="display:block;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet and your css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following css for the form :

```
position:absolute;
left: 50%;
top : 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css snippet, which follows latest feature of flexbox styling:

```
body {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```